# button not exactly centered in it's parent

Tags: android-layout

I am surprised, i did not notice this during my 6 months of development time on Android. I have a realtivelayout whose bottom is aligned to the bottom of the screen/parent. I wanted to place a button at the center of this relativelayout. I notice that the button is not exactly centered vertically. There appears to be couple of pixels between the bottom of the button and that of the relativeLayout. Here's the piece of relevant layout code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#888">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ping">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas? My targetSDK is 2.2 and above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only on the bottom of it, is it? Isn't that odd? I see other apps where the button is centered. May be they adjusted for this built-in padding by adding their own on the top side? Thanks.